# Hide InfoPath 2010 section on display of a filled out form if no fields in that section were filled

Tags: 2010, list, infopath

When a person clicks on a list item, I'd like to hide a section of the form if no fields were filled out. So, for instance, if we had a travel request form and the person didn't fill out anything for upgrades, they would not see that section when they click on the list item in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a [section control](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-containers-and-group-controls-HA101783361.aspx) for each category that you want to hide and include the content of the category that you wish to hide in the section.

Once the sections are created, you will have to add a rule to each section that hides it based on the user's selection.

To add a rule:

1. Click the section
2. On the home ribbon, click Manage rules
3. In the rules box select new > formatting
4. Create the condition (e.g., if upgrades is blank)
5. Select 'hide this control'

That should do it.  Also [this](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/How-to-hide-a-group-of-fields-in-a-SharePoint-list-using-InfoPath-2010.aspx) should help.